# error "date[("get" + method)] is not a function" with Big Calendar with date-fns

Tags: reactjs, date-fns, react-big-calendar

I am new at using this API and that I am not yet used to their documentation. I have problem with my calendar project, where I use react-big-calendar with date-fns and DateTimePicker https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-datetime-picker, I use the DateTimePicker to manually input title, start and end date and time and be saved into localstorage. [Calendar Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJPIt.jpg)

It would save successfully into localstorage, but the page will go blank when viewing it in week and day and when I try to check in the localstorage that to me there is nothing wrong with the data when I compare with existing date and the my test input. I dont know where it went wrong.

```
import format from "date-fns/format"
import parse from 'date-fns/parse'
import startOfWeek from 'date-fns/startOfWeek'
import getDay from 'date-fns/getDay'
import { dateFnsLocalizer } from "react-big-calendar"
import DateTimePicker from "react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker"
import 'react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.css'
import 'react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css'
import 'react-clock/dist/Clock.css'
import { Calendar } from "react-big-calendar"
import 'react-big-calendar/lib/css/react-big-calendar.css'
import events from "../data/events"

const locales ={
"en-US" : require("date-fns/locale/en-US")
}

const localizer = dateFnsLocalizer({
format,
parse,
startOfWeek,
getDay,
locales
})

function Body() {
const [ newEvent, setNewEvent ] = useState({ title: "", start: "", end: ""})
/const [ allEvents, setAllEvents ] = useState(events)/
/const [currentEvent, setCurrentEvent] = useState("")/

const [ allEvents, setAllEvents ] = useState(() => {

    const savedEvents = localStorage.getItem("events")

    if (savedEvents) {
        return JSON.parse(savedEvents)
    } else {
        return events
    }
})

useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("events", JSON.stringify(allEvents))
}, [allEvents])

function handleAddEvent(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    
    if (newEvent !== "") {
        setAllEvents([
            ...allEvents,
            newEvent
        ])
    }
    
    console.log(newEvent)
    setNewEvent({ title: "", start: "", end: "" })
}  

return (
    <div className="cal-body">
        <div className="picker">
            <input 
                type="text"
                value={newEvent.title} 
                onChange={(e) => setNewEvent({...newEvent, title: e.target.value})}
            />
            <DateTimePicker
                disableClock={true}
                disableCalendar={true}
                selected={newEvent.start}
                dayPlaceholder="dd"
                monthPlaceholder="mm"
                yearPlaceholder="yyyy"
                hourPlaceholder="hh"
                minutePlaceholder="mm"
                onChange={(start) => setNewEvent({...newEvent, start})}
            />
            <DateTimePicker
                disableClock={true}
                disableCalendar={true}
                style={{
                    background: "white"
                }}
                selected={newEvent.end}
                dayPlaceholder="dd"
                monthPlaceholder="mm"
                yearPlaceholder="yyyy"
                hourPlaceholder="hh"
                minutePlaceholder="mm"
                onChange={(end) => setNewEvent({...newEvent, end})}
            />
            <button className="button" onClick={handleAddEvent}>Add</button>
        </div>
        
        <div className="calendar">
            <Calendar
                selectable
                localizer={localizer}
                events={allEvents}
                startAccessor="start"
                endAccessor="end"
                popup="true"
                onSelectEvent={() => setOpenModal(true)}
                style={{ 
                    height: 500, 
                    margin:"50px", 
                    background: "white", 
                    color: "black",
                    border: "2px solid black" }}
            />
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Body
```

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when RBC is getting something other than a true js `Date` instance for one of the date type props (`date`, event `start` and `end`, etc). Getting those `events` from `localStorage` your `event`s would have string values for the `start` and `end` dates. You would need some form of preprocessor method that would convert them from the UTC string values to true js `Date` objects.